# How do I prompt the user for input with a popup window?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a ListView full of elements filling the screen. When I tap one, I want a popup to appear asking for a confirmation (so an Ok and a Cancel button), and then conveniently close the dialog and access the user response so that my main activity can do something with it. I may want to add extra inputs to the dialog later on, and therefore I may also need a more complex form of user response than just ok/cancel.

There are plenty of questions about this here, but they're all focused on a specific way to do it. I haven't even gotten that far yet. There seems to be at least three different ways that it could be done (Dialogs, AlertDialogs, and DialogFragments), and out of those I'm not sure if I'm supposed to subclass them, pass them to the FragmentManager, use a combination of them, or sacrifice a lamb to Poseidon.

I really need a detailed explanation, I tried [this](http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/prompt-dialog-for-android.html) code example but I can't get it working the way I want (can't get a custom layout on it - I tried setView but nothing it happening).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for here is a combination of a customized Dialog with an interface between the current fragment/activity and the dialog it self.

1. Create a dialog that looks just as you like. (Just as explained at the link above)
2. Then create an interface and declare methods to be called when things happen in the dialog (like data input and such)
3. Implement activity as listener of that interface, and when calling the create-dialog method, pass the activity in the parameters.
4. In the creation method require a Listener of the interface to be passed in the params (your activity)
5. Call whatever method in the interface whenever inside the dialog like activity.methodOfInterface();
6. If you implemented correctly methodOfInterface() in activity, the method there will be called.